# Cookie is not set on Production when I add domain option when setting cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, vercel

I host my application on `vercel.com`. At first the cookie is not working at all, I tried to add the options in the cookie by many solutions like

```
{
  path: '/',
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'none'
}
```

and it works but unfortunately, it appeared as the cookie is not shown in the browser, but on the api the cookie is set which made me confused. So I thought maybe I forgot to add `domain` option when setting cookie, then I added `domain` in the cookie option like:

```
{
  domain: 'mydomain.me'
  path: '/',
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'none'
}
```

Then the cookie is not working again and I when I checked in `Network` it said, `this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url`.

What really went wrong here, why the cookie is not set when I add `domain` option?
And when I did not add `domain` why the cookie is set but not showing on the browser?